# Use cases where PendingIntent is used

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am trying to see how PendingIntents are useful. Can you provide examples of apps where PendingIntents are used?

I am not looking for examples of code, but real life use cases where PendingIntents are used, with a bit of explaination.

Thanks,

Comment: `AlarmManager`...explanation: to set an Intent for the future, yes the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell, `PendingIntent` lets you authorize a different application to execute an `Intent` on your behalf, i.e. as you and with your permissions.

A typical case would be passing a `PendingIntent` to the `NotificationManager`. It could have an `Intent` to open an activity that is private to your application.

If you're passing intents within your application you don't have to deal with `PendingIntent`.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) has a pretty good explanation of this.

Comment: "If you're passing intents within your application you don't have to deal with PendingIntent.", what about `AlarmManager`?

Comment: In this case, you're passing it to the framework's `AlarmManager` (which is outside your app) to execute it on your behalf. Just as with `NotificationManager` (again a framework class).